# Smack - How to read a MultiUserChat's configuration?

Tags: java, xmpp, smack, multiuserchat

I tried to create a multiuserchat with Java. I'm using smack library. 
Here is my code to create multiuserchat:

```
MultiUserChat muc = new MultiUserChat(connection, "roomname@somehost");
muc.create("mynickname");

Form form = muc.getConfigurationForm();
Form submitForm = form.createAnswerForm();
submitForm.setAnswer("muc#roomconfig_roomname", "A nice formatted Room Name");
submitForm.setAnswer("muc#roomconfig_roomdesc", "The description. It should be longer.");
muc.sendConfigurationForm(submitForm);
muc.addMessageListener(mucMessageListener); // mucMessageListener is a PacketListener
```

Then, I tried to capture the message sent by this room created above using mucMessageListener:

```
private PacketListener mucMessageListener = new PacketListener() {
    public void processPacket(Packet packet) {
        if (packet instanceof Message) {
            Message message = (Message) packet;
            // this is where I got the problem
        }
    }
}
```

As the message received by other part (the user who is not the owner of this multiuserchat), can he somehow get the value set in this line above:

```
submitForm.setAnswer("muc#roomconfig_roomname", "A nice formatted Room Name");
```

You see, getting just the JID of the room is not really good for the view. I expect I could have a String which value is "A nice formatted Room Name".

How can we get that?

Answer (score 1):

You can easily get its configurations like name and etc from this code:

```
MultiUserChatManager mucManager = MultiUserChatManager.getInstanceFor(connection);
RoomInfo info = mucManager.getRoomInfo(room.getRoom());
```

now you can get its informations like this:

```
String mucName = info.getName();
Boolean isPersistence = info.isPersistent();
```

and etc.

Comment: I'm using this code in my app using smack and openfire. Can you tell me what's your error, dear @Nilax?

Comment: I am doing exactly the same.  

muc.create(Resourcepart.from(nickName));

Form form = muc.getConfigurationForm();
Form submitForm = form.createAnswerForm();
submitForm.setAnswer("muc#roomconfig_persistentroom", true);
submitForm.setAnswer("muc#roomconfig_membersonly", true);
submitForm.setAnswer("muc#roomconfig_roomdesc", room_desc);
muc.sendConfigurationForm(submitForm);

Can you please suggest me where I am wrong in setting and getting details?

Comment: Your code for creating MUC is fine, if you sure that muc is created and you invited some one to it using multiUserChat.invite(...) , then must my code works in  invitationReceived() method that already added using mMUCManager.addInvitationListener(...)

Answer (score 0):

Retrieving the value of `muc#roomconfig_romname` is described in [XEP-45 6.4](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0045.html#disco-roominfo). Smack provides the [`MultiUserChat.getRoomInfo()`](http://www.igniterealtime.org/builds/smack/docs/latest/javadoc/org/jivesoftware/smackx/muc/MultiUserChat.html) method to perform the query.

```
RoomInfo roomInfo = MultiUserChat.getRoomInfo(connection, "roomname@somehost.com")
String roomDescription = roomInfo.getDescription()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to read a value of var for example title name of room in config

```
Form form = chat.getConfigurationForm();
String value =  form.getField("muc#roomconfig_roomname").getValues().next();
```

then do what ever you want with value..